# How to find a memory leak in Java / Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, memory-leaks

I am having a lot of trouble with a memory leak in one of our apps and not sure where to look next. I know similar questions have been asked but none had any answers that were helpful.

When we use the profiler in android studio it shows that "native" memory increases quite rapidly, and after using the app for roughly 10-15 minutes it will crash from a memory leak.

Our app is written entirely in java and kotlin, I've looked through for any static object, or objects kept in companion objects that may not be collected by the garbage collector, but there are none other than a few static strings like a `TAG` for logging.

We tried using leak canary but it can't seem to find any memory leaks and keeps telling us our app is fine. I even intentionally added a leak by holding onto an android activity context statically just to ensure leak canary was working, and it was.

Are there any other things I should look out for that may be causing memory leaks in my java code? Any specific objects that I may be holding onto causing this?

Comment: Are you sure it's a leak and not an OOM caused by just doing something silly in the code?

Comment: @ThomasCook Not entirely sure, based on how java works I has assumed it must be something we are keeping reference to that is building in size, otherwise it would be garbage collected. However I can't find any static variables (or even global class variables) that are growing. I'm assuming there must be something silly we are doing but I'm not sure how to even begin looking for it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure leak canary would catch it if it was a leak is all. Look for any parts of the code that are doing heavy loops, maybe creating huge strings without being super obvious. You say you profile it, is there a way you can look at the call stack at the point in time where you observe the heap growing and then look at the code around that area to see if there is unsafe allocations of strings/byte arrays?

Comment: Can you consistently reproduce it? If so, you've already won half the battle. If it's intermittent, I would start by looking for any async code in and around the offending area of the code base (which you can hopefully infer based on where the issue is happening)

Comment: Are you doing any recursion?

Comment: @ThomasCook I can reproduce it easily, Ill try looking at the call stack and see what i find in the profiler... I think you just gave me an idea of what it might be so I hope my suspicion is correct, will update in a bit.

Comment: Nice one, do keep us updated here :thumbsup:

Comment: Any progress Quin?

Comment: @ThomasCook Not really, maybe, I'm not sure... We found that it seems like the object that is filling memory is byte[], and it seems like its pointing to a specific byte[] which is taken as  a parameter to a method which will call itself recursively to parse the byte[] in chunks. But the byte[] in this method is not static or global so I'm not sure why it wouldn't be garbage collected after the method completes. (The method does complete eventually)... But i think we have narrowed it down to likely being something to do with that method.

Comment: @ThomasCook We are using this [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) class and calling allocate. I'm not sure if maybe that class has something special about it to let it persist in memory?

Comment: Hmm, well each time the method is recursively called you'll be adding onto a stack, so you could have a StackOverflow problem. Until the recursion has ended this entire stack won't be cleaned up by the GC, so you could have an OOM caused by that.

Could you post the recursive function in the question by editting it?

Comment: Are you using Java or Kotlin? If using Kotlin you may be able to optimize your recursive function to use tail recursion, which the compiler will optimize to a loop in the byte code. The upshot of this is that the GC will clean up variables scoped to that loop each time it loops, unlike non tail recursion where it builds up the stack until the recursion ends.

Comment: Bear in mind, a recursive function can always be expressed as a loop, so if worst comes to worst you can just remove the admittedly sexy recursion and express the same logic as a loop. Post the offending code and I'll take a look

Comment: @ThomasCook we use both, though the recursive method that I'm suspect of is in Java. I've got a couple other things to try first but if unsuccessful then maybe i will convert the file to kotlin and try what you're suggesting. The function is kind of huge and full of a bunch of spaghetti code calling many other functions that then recall the recursive function... So it will be a bit of work to post  minimal version of it. Though I may give it a go if I'm stuck on this  much longer :P

Comment: Oh I see haha, in that case you have 2 problems, and a rather tasty dish (spaghetti + recursion) :P

Comment: @ThomasCook The problem has been fixed! It ended up not being a memory issue at all. The crash would say `OutOfMemory` so we had assumed it was, but then I found a log message saying `pthread_create failed` and I thought, hmm thats weird what does our CPU usage look like... We had over 4000 threads!!! Turns out that recursive method was spinning up a bunch of threads (which was rapidly increasing our memory) and none of the threads were exiting. Switched it to use a thread pool instead of just spinning up a new thread, and all issues were solved.

Comment: @ThomasCook We had been so focused on the OOM and looking at the memory tab in profiler we hadn't even noticed the CPU xD - Anyway my brain is mush now, what a fun adventure that was. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Damn haha good job, happy weekend!

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio you can generate a heap dump by pressing the Dump Java heap button:
[image: Dump Java Heap Button]

here you can see how much which class is using memory. for example, you might find a class that should have been collected by garbage collector but didn't.

**update:
as you stated the problem is with native memory allocation, but I would keep this answer cause it might help someone else.

Comment: Thanks, I've been using the profiler to do this, but haven't had any luck. I found all the memory thats increasing falls under the "Native" category, seems like byte[] and String are the two objects that are taking up the most size...